# formik doesn't keep its state

Tags: reactjs, formik

So I have a viewModel with my formik Object with schema and handleChange methods. I import the formik object into my containers, like that:

```
export const MyViewModel = () => {

const [valueA, setValueA] = useState(valueA)

const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {}
})}

onChangeValuesHandler = (event) => {
  formik.handleChange(event);
  setValueA(event.target.value);
}
```

In the main container:

```
<form onSubmit={submitHandler} >
  <ContainerA {...props} />
  <ContainerB {...props} />
</form>
```

In containerA:

```
const containerA = () => {
  const { formik, valueA } = useMyViewModel();
}
```

The problem is that the formik object seems to be reinitialized every time I move from one container to other changing values and so the formik.touched object changes everytime and contains only the fields of the last container touched.
How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Where you use MyViewModel ? How do you change your containers? Description not clear, can you give reproducible example